# Where would I run this validateForm method? I'm a very newbie PHP developer getting the hang of web developing

Tags: php, methods

Here's what I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <?php
    $validForm = false;

    function getValue($field){
        if(isset($_GET[$field])){
            return $_GET[$field];
        }
        else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    function validateForm(){
     //magic goes here.   
    }        
    ?>
</head>

<body>
    <?php if($validForm == false){ ?>
    <form action="class2.php" method="get">
        <dl>
            <dt>First Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getValue('name')) ?>" name="name" />                    
            </dd>                

            <dt>Last Name:</dt>
            <dd><input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(getValue('lastname')) ?>" name="lastname" />                    
            </dd>

            <br />                
            <dt>
                <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
            </dt>                
        </dl>
    </form>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>

    <h1>Congratulations, you succesfully filled out the form!</h1>

    <?php }
    ?>
</body>
```

Where would I put the validateForm() call? I'm not sure.
What I want is to continue showing the form until the $validForm variable is true. :)

Thank you SO you always help me out.

Comment: Framework recommendations in 3...2...

Comment: I'm a beginner. I'd rather do things like this to learn basics. I'll eventually go with a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validateForm(){
 if ( ) // Your form conditions go here
 {
    return true;
 } else {
    return false;
 }
} 
if ( $_GET ) // Only validate the form if it was submitted
{
   $validForm = validateForm();
} else {
   $validForm = false;
}
```

Examples for some conditions:

```
if ( !empty ( $_GET[ 'name' ] ) and !empty ( $_GET[ 'lastname' ] ) ) // Check if the user entered something in both fields
```

**I can only recommend you to change your `getValue` function too.**

It would be a good idea to change

```
return $_GET[$field];
```

to something like

```
return htmlspecialchars ( trim ( $_GET[$field] ) );
```

This will remove unnecessary whitespace and escape the output at once.

The next or probably first step you should take would be to change your form from `GET` to `POST` as it is, in most cases, a bad idea to send form data via `GET`.

Comment: GET is useful if you want users to be able to bookmark certain areas. :) Thank you for your help. I used the trim() method as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a name to your submit button :

```
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="validate" />
```

And after the declaration of validateForm

you put

```
if(getValue("validate") != "")
validateForm();
```

Comment: This assumes that the submit button will be a successful control. It usually will be, but there are exceptions (especially once you leave this *specific* case). Better to use a hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd check for the $_POST-variables in your getValue-function as you're trying to validate form-data (your checking $_GET-variables which is data submitted through the URL), you also may want to add "trim"
2. give the submit-button an id and check if the form has beed submitted that way

e.g. `<input type="submit" value="enviar" id="submitButton" />`

setting $validForm would look this this: `$validForm = validateForm();` (instead of "$validForm = false;")

your validateForm-function should then check whether "$_POST["submitButton"]" is set and if your data is valid (set, right type, etc. etc.), if all of that is ok, return "true", otherwise "false"

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
  <?php
    $validForm = validateForm();
```

C.